# Excluding rows from a data.table based on sort order

Tags: r, data.table

I need some help filtering a data.table in R. I had a file with **millions** of rows with 4 words each.

I want to remove some rows that I don't need. Each row has 4 words and a frequency.

I want to keep just the 3 with "most frequency" for each combo of the first 3 words.

Bellow are a example of the data.table and what I need as an output.

```
text <- c("Run to the hills", "Run to the mountains", "Run to the highway", "Run to the top", "Run to the horizon",
          "Go away with him", "Go away with her",
          "I am a good", "I am a bad", "I am a uggly", "I am a guy", "I am a woman",
          "I am the most")

frequency <- c(0.1, 0.09, 0.2, 0.05, 0.001,
               0.05, 0.04,
               0.1, 0.06, 0.3, 0.05, 0.1,
               0.2)

DT <- data.table(text = text, frequency = frequency)

#Original output:
                    text frequency
 1:     Run to the hills     0.100
 2: Run to the mountains     0.090
 3:   Run to the highway     0.200
 4:       Run to the top     0.050
 5:   Run to the horizon     0.001
 6:     Go away with him     0.050
 7:     Go away with her     0.040
 8:          I am a good     0.100
 9:           I am a bad     0.060
10:         I am a uggly     0.300
11:           I am a guy     0.050
12:         I am a woman     0.100
13:         I am awesome     0.200
```

Output needed: (Just the top 3 frequency from same "first 3 words")

```
                 text frequency
  1: Go away with him      0.05     
  2: Go away with her      0.04
  3: I am a uggly          0.30  
  4: I am a woman          0.10
  5: I am a good           0.10
  6: I am the most         0.20
  7: Run to the highway    0.20
  8: Run to the hills      0.10
  9: Run to the mountains 0.09
```

So, I want to keep just the top 3 sorted by the frequency column: "Run to the XXXXX", "Go away with XXXXX", "I am a XXXXX", "I am the XXXXX"

In this case, I would drop: "Run to the top", "Run to the horizon", "I am a bad", "I am a guy"

I was thinking in something with regex, but I am kinda lost right now :-\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an id column with `sub()` that consists of the first three words, then use that to take the top three values of frequency.

Easier done than said ...

```
library(data.table)

## add an id column containing only the first three words
DT[, id := sub(" \\S+$", "", text)]
## order by frequency, take the top three by id, remove id and NAs
## and with a little help from Frank :)
na.omit(
  DT[order(frequency, decreasing = TRUE), .SD[1:3], keyby = id][, id := NULL][]
)
#                    text frequency
# 1:     Go away with him      0.05
# 2:     Go away with her      0.04
# 3:         I am a uggly      0.30
# 4:          I am a good      0.10
# 5:         I am a woman      0.10
# 6:        I am the most      0.20
# 7:   Run to the highway      0.20
# 8:     Run to the hills      0.10
# 9: Run to the mountains      0.09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DT[,group := sub(" \\S+$", "", text)]
DT[,grank:=base::rank(-frequency),by=group]
DT[grank <= 3]
```

Used the rank function so OP can specify what to do with ties.

Comment: Fixed. I prefer to use data.table syntax only where necessary.

Comment: Base syntax should be encouraged except where necessary (or has performance impacts). Otherwise you end up with maintainability issues down the line, e.g. a package updates and your code needs fixing.

Comment: As I clearly stated above, it says except where necessary or has performance impacts. data.table can be very useful from a memory and speed perspective and I would encourage it for those purposes.

Comment: Not at all, using the := operator is better than the $, from a performance perspective. I do agree wholeheartedly with the use of := for performance, however my comment was in general about base syntax not about your specific change.